# solving differential equation with delta function without transformation

Tags: derivatives

[image]

How Can I solve this problem without Laplace transform.... My professor said that I can solve the differential equation problem with delta function forcing by integrating over the momentum of impulse. don't understand integral part; ![enter image description here][2]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Let $z=y+y'$. Then use the method of variation of constants twice.

Comment: I added example what professor gave to me.. but I don't understand integral part;